# Retrieving json data from external server

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, openstreetmap

I asked a similar question to this earlier but perhaps this is a bit more clear.

I am trying to retrieve json data from the OSRM routing server (API here: https://github.com/DennisOSRM/Project-OSRM/wiki/Server-api).

I am currently using this code:

http://jsfiddle.net/FhfVW/10/

```
$(function () {
$("#getJSON").click(function () {
    var url = "http://router.project-osrm.org/viaroute?loc=51.500,0.100&loc=51.500,0.1001&jsonp=myroute";
    $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url: url,
        jsonpCallback: 'myroute',
        success: function (data) {
            test = data.route_geometry;
            alert(test);
        }
    });
});
});
```

However I don't get any response from this. Eveidently something is wrong, although I've tried it removing the callbacks and 'jsonp=myroute' part with no success either.

Thanks for any help.

Nick

Comment: can you add the error function on the ajax call to see what the exact problem  is?

Comment: And does this server set CORS headers so that you can get the result ?

Comment: oh, and what is the response you're getting from the server? can you see it in the developer tools of the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, i got this working

```
$(function () {
    var url = "http://router.project-osrm.org/viaroute?loc=51.500,0.100&loc=51.500,0.1001";
    $.ajax(url, {dataType:"jsonp", jsonp:"jsonp", cache:true}).success(function() {
       console.log(arguments);
    });
});
```

if you put the url into the browser, which gets generated by jquery, then you see a 400 error, as jquery adds the "&*=[TIMESTAMP]" param. But your remote server says, the url is then malformed. If you give jquery the "cache" option with a true value, it will not append the "*" parameter.

If you have further issues, try to replace the "success" with the "always" callback, as you will then be notified every time the callback succeds or not. Because sometimes there is an error within jquery, which you wouldnt notice in developer tools

Comment: Thankyou so much! I had to fiddle with the code a little bit to get it functioning, but now it seems to be working here (http://jsfiddle.net/FhfVW/11/).